# How to create a folder in external sdcard?

Tags: android, memory, android-sdcard

I have a task to save  the .txt in external SDCard(Not Device memory). I tried in all ways. I can't get the required output. The folder created and saved in internal device sdcard only. I used the following code.

```
 private File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath() + "/Research/"+filname+".txt");
```

I also put the following code in Manifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But it is not working. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "it is not working" => LogCat or at least actual/expected output. Without that, we would just be guessing what's wrong.

Comment: what kind of error you get please see logcat and tell us

Comment: you can use `fileObject.mkdir();` or `fileObject.mkdirs();` to create new folder/folders

Comment: I didn't get any errors. It just create folder in device memory only not in Removable sdcard.

Comment: How can you understand the folder is created in internal device sdcard and not in external sdcard?

Comment: I saw that a folder created in device memory.But not in external  sdcard.

Comment: Where did you test and see? Emulator or real device? In file explorer in DDMS or by going to your device root folder via PC?

Comment: Directly in device(Samsung Galaxy S4). I put the removable SD card into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can determine the path to removable media (Micro SD card) reliably on Android. So stop trying. Better ask the user to indicate that path.

Comment: Ok sir. If the device memory full, Is that possible to store data in sdcard or not. Client asks me like that.

Comment: Yes if the device memory is full you can store data on removable media if there is removable media and the removable media is not full and the removable media is writable which is mostly not the case under kitkat. But why a new question? Please react to my answer first.

Comment: how we can access the removable media?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Above code return "/storage/sdcard0", But if you want to make a folder on external SD Card you need "/storage/sdcard1". so try to do something like this

```
private File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().replace("0", "1")
    .getAbsolutePath() + "/Research/"+filname+".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

USE [mkDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) or [mkDirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) to create new Folder/Folders:

```
private File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath() + "/Research/");
mPath.mkDir();

 mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath() + "/Research/"+filname+".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this can help you but I had a same problem and this code solved it. Create this private class:

```
private class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

    private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
    private File mFile;

    public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
        mFile = f;
        mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
        mMs.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        mMs.disconnect();
    }

}
```

After creating the file call this:

```
new SingleMediaScanner(MainActivity.this, file);
```

I hope this can help you.